# Java: unparseable date exception

Tags: java, date, format

While trying to transform the date format I get an exception:unparseable date and don't know how to fix this problem.

I am receiving a string which represents an event date and would like to display this date in different format in GUI.

What I was trying to do is the following:

```
private String modifyDateLayout(String inputDate){
        try {
            //inputDate = "2010-01-04 01:32:27 UTC";
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").parse(inputDate);
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "15.01.2010";
        }
    }
```

Anyway the line

```
String modifiedDateString = originalDate.toString();
```

is dummy. I would like to get a date string in the following format:

> dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss

and the input String example is the following:

> 2010-01-04 01:32:27 UTC

Does anyone know how to convert the example date (String) above into a String format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss?

Thank you!

Edit: I fixed the wrong input date format but still it doesn't work. Above is the pasted method and below is the screen image from debugging session.

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/193/dateproblem.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/193/dateproblem.png)

**#Update**
I ran

```
String[] timezones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

and there is UTC String in the array. It's a strange problem.

I did a dirty hack that works:

```
private String modifyDateLayout(String inputDate){
    try {
        inputDate = inputDate.replace(" UTC", "");
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(inputDate);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "15.01.2010";
    }
}
```

But still I would prefer to transform the original input without cutting timezone away.

This code is written for Android phone using JDK 1.6.

Comment: I know this is a long ago thread but to clarify doubts regarding the parse exception when "UTC" is in the date format. The code is broken in Android.

[Android bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14963)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What you're basically doing here is relying on [`Date#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) which already has a fixed pattern. To convert a Java `Date` object into another human readable String pattern, you need [`SimpleDateFormat#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29).

```
private String modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) throws ParseException{
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").parse(inputDate);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);
}
```

By the way, the "unparseable date" exception can here **only** be thrown by [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29). This means that the `inputDate` isn't in the expected pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"`. You'll probably need to modify the pattern to match the `inputDate`'s actual pattern.

**Update:** Okay, I did a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inputDate = "2010-01-04 01:32:27 UTC";
    String newDate = new Test().modifyDateLayout(inputDate);
    System.out.println(newDate);
}
```

This correctly prints:

```
03.01.2010 21:32:27
```

(I'm on GMT-4)

**Update 2:** as per your edit, you really got a `ParseException` on that. The most suspicious part would then be the timezone of `UTC`. Is this actually *known* at your Java environment? What Java version and what OS version are you using? Check [`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29). There must be a `UTC` in between.

Comment: The problem is that the line Date date = formatter.parse(inputDate);
throws an exception. I fixed the input format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z but it still throws an exception.

Comment: I expected that, see my edit which was added before you commented on. If you want more assistance on finding the right pattern, you'll need to post an example of the **actual** `inputDate` value.

Comment: I'm having this trouble to parse this date: "11/10/2011 06:03:19 p.m."

Comment: If you have 'T' in date format (e.g. "2018-01-31T16:01:49") use this date format DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error working in Talend. I was able to store S3 CSV files created from Redshift without a problem. The error occurred when I was trying to load the same S3 CSV files into an Amazon RDS MySQL database. I tried the default timestamp Talend timestamp formats but they were throwing exception:unparseable date when loading into MySQL.

This from the accepted answer helped me solve this problem:

> By the way, the "unparseable date" exception can here only be thrown by SimpleDateFormat#parse(). This means that the inputDate isn't in the expected pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z". You'll probably need to modify the pattern to match the inputDate's actual pattern

The key to my solution was changing the Talend schema. Talend set the timestamp field to "date" so I changed it to "timestamp" then I inserted "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" into the format string column view a screenshot here [talend schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVPbY.jpg)

I had other issues with 12 hour and 24 hour timestamp translations until I added the "z" at the end of the timestamp string.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle docs, [Date.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) method convert [Date object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to a String of the specific form - do not use toString method on Date object. Try to use:

```
String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat(YOUR_STRING_PATTERN).format(yourDateObject);
```

Next step is parse stringDate to Date:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(OUTPUT_PATTERN).parse(stringDate);
```

Note that, [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method throws ParseException