# Unparseable date: "2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00"

Tags: java, date

Following code throws the exception when try to parse from the string (2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00):

```
image.setLastUpdated(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
    .parse(imageElement.getAttribute("lastUpdate")))
```

I have also tried the following format:

```
image.setLastUpdated(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    .parse(imageElement.getAttribute("lastUpdate")));
```

But I get the same exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.discavo.ImportManagerGiata.parseImageXML(ImportManagerGiata.java:204)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception
In that thread there is a good solution...

Comment: @RafaRomero: Not for a value in this format, there isn't.

Comment: Oh sorry @JonSkeet!! You are right! my apologies!

Answer (score 5):

You need `X` as the specifier for the UTC offset as it's in ISO-8601 format, as per the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
```

Comment: Wonder how they got the name "SimpleDateFormat" through peer review!

Comment: Work, thanks a lot. I don't know how I overlooked the X option in java  doc, but thanks!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen At the time `SimpleDateFormat` was first added to Java, ISO-8601 was not widely used (maybe it didn't even exist yet). The `X` specifier was added in Java 7.

Comment: @Jesper Actually the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard was published in the decade *prior* to Java's existence. And that style was in use in international business even earlier. The blame for poor date-time handling in Java belongs to the lack of research and thoughtfulness that went into the java.util.Date/Calendar classes. This part of the Java platform was rushed to market too early. Rectified by Joda-Time now and [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) soon in Java 8.

Comment: The `Z` specifier at least corresponds to *some* standard (RFC 822, according to the docs). But I agree that Java's `Date` and `Calendar` API is quite poor, and we should have had something like JSR-310 a long time ago...

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Your Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00");
        System.out.println(odt);

        // ########### In case you need Instant ###########
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
        
        // Java-12 onwards, you can parse the ISO-8601 compliant Date-Time with timezone
        // information directly into Instant
        instant = Instant.parse("2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00");
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00
2011-12-08T01:01:02Z
2011-12-08T01:01:02Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/FoxBQl)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20402918/642706) is correct. But FYI…

## No problem in Joda-Time

The problem presented by this question does not exist if using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) rather than the mess that is the java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java.

Joda-Time 2.3 has a variety of built-in parsers, so no need to specify a format in this case. Use methods on the [ISODateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) class to retrieve a variety of formatters designed to parse variations of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings.

The question fails to account for time zone. So I am showing all three possibilities:

- You want the time converted to a **specific time zone**.
  *Denver* in this example.
- You want the time adjusted to **UTC**, for no time offset.
  Common for storage or further date-time work.
- You want to preserve this date-time with **its offset**.
  Not usually a good idea, as you have neither the benefit of UTC (no offset and no need to worry about Daylight Saving Time DST or other issues), nor the benefit of a named time zone with rules to handle DST or other issues.

### For Desired Time Zone

```java
// For desired time zone. Arbitrarily using 'Denver' as named time zone for this example.
DateTimeZone denverTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Denver" );
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInDenver = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withZone(denverTimeZone).parseDateTime( "2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00" );
System.out.println( "dateTimeInDenver: " + dateTimeInDenver );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInDenver: 2011-12-07T18:01:02.000-07:00
```

### For UTC

```java
// For UTC (no offset).
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeInUTC = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withZoneUTC().parseDateTime( "2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00" );
System.out.println( dateTimeInUTC );
```

When run…

```
2011-12-08T01:01:02.000Z
```

### For Offset As Parsed

```java
// For offset as parsed. 
// Least beneficial, as no rules for Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies can be applied.
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTimeWithOffsetParsed = org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime( "2011-12-08T02:01:02+01:00" );
System.out.println( "dateTimeWithOffsetParsed: " + dateTimeWithOffsetParsed );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeWithOffsetParsed: 2011-12-08T02:01:02.000+01:00
```