# Java : String to Date conversion Getting Unparseable Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am getting date in String as `09/16/2012 15:57`. How do i convert it in `java.util.Date`

I have tried :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSS a");
dateFormat.parse(res.getString("stringdate"));
```

But getting `unparseable exception`

Plz suggest.

Comment: And the stack trace is  ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: unparseable date exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception)

Answer (score 6):

You date time pattern is not correct. Try to match the input string

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date pattern does not match the given date string. Try the following:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    dateFormat.parse(res.getString("stringdate"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You date time pattern is not correct.Many of the datetime format is there
 Try to match correct input string

Example
String dateStr = "2011-09-19T15:57:11Z";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateStr);
```

**Patterns are**

"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT

"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"              Wed, Jul 4, '01

"h:mm a"                        12:08 PM

"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"         12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time

"K:mm a, z"                     0:08 PM, PDT

"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"  02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM

"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"    Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700

"yyMMddHHmmssZ"                 010704120856-0700

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"    2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700