# Filter results using createdOn filter

Tags: java, hibernate

```
if(param.startsWith("FILTER_PARAM_")) {
    String value = WebUtils.deriveParam(param, request.getParameterMap());
    String field =  param.split("_")[2];
    if("createdOn".equalsIgnoreCase(field)){
        try {
            Date filterDate = ConversionUtils.convertFromString(value);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS aa");
            value = timeFormat.format(filterDate);
            params.put("createdDate", value);
        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            // TODO Empty results
        }
    } else {
        params.put(field, value);
    }
}

public static String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

public static Date convertFromString(String dateString) throws Exception {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(dateString)) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        return formatter.parse(dateString);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In DB, the column is '`CreatedDate`' : **TIMESTAMP(6), e.g. 25-AUG-14 11.26.16.369000000 AM**

On UI, the user gives the Date String as "**08/25/2014**".

I have to filter the columns with the given Date.
Tried with the above code, it is giving the following exception:

```
2014-09-11 12:21:14,749 DEBUG [http-8081-29] c.h.u.e.DefaultExceptionLoggingHandler [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:132] Resolving exception from handler [public com.hcentive.utils.search.datatable.model.DatatableSearchResponse com.hcentive.agent.web.controller.CoverPageTemplateController.getTemplatesList(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]: com.hcentive.utils.exception.HCException: GENERIC_ERROR:Unknown Error has happened
2014-09-11 12:21:14,752 ERROR [http-8081-29] c.h.u.e.DefaultExceptionLoggingHandler [DefaultExceptionLoggingHandler.java:64] Some unknown error has happened, please try again later.{Actual Message- GENERIC_ERROR:Unknown Error has happened}
com.hcentive.utils.exception.HCException: GENERIC_ERROR:Unknown Error has happened
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.service.CriteriaBasedSearchService.search(CriteriaBasedSearchService.java:49) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.service.CriteriaBasedSearchService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3afe362.invoke(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191) ~[cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) ~[spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.service.CriteriaBasedSearchService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a6c400e4.search(<generated>) ~[cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.web.QuerySearchController.search(QuerySearchController.java:21) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.datatable.web.DatatableSearchController.search(DatatableSearchController.java:42) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.datatable.web.DatatableSearchController.search(DatatableSearchController.java:35) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.agent.web.controller.CoverPageTemplateController.getTemplatesList(CoverPageTemplateController.java:150) ~[agent-web-hix-1.5.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213) ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.agent.web.filter.AssistorFilter.doFilterInternal(AssistorFilter.java:131) [agent-web-hix-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129) [sitemesh-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77) [sitemesh-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.hcentive.utils.security.filter.PasswordChangeFilter.doFilterInternal(PasswordChangeFilter.java:87) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.hcentive.co.common.web.security.filter.CGIRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CGIRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:135) [co-common-1.0-Snapshot.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.utils.web.xss.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:37) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.utils.web.xss.filter.LocaleConfigurerFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleConfigurerFilter.java:40) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.utils.web.flash.FlashMapFilter.doFilterInternal(FlashMapFilter.java:70) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.utils.web.cookie.CookieEnabledFilter.doFilterInternal(CookieEnabledFilter.java:55) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at com.hcentive.utils.web.clickjack.ClickJackFilter.doFilterInternal(ClickJackFilter.java:27) [utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291) [catalina.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11-Sep-14 00:00:00.000000000 AM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
    at com.hcentive.utils.orm.hibernate.HibernateCriteriaUtils.getSubCriterion(HibernateCriteriaUtils.java:323) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.orm.hibernate.HibernateCriteriaUtils.buidCriteria(HibernateCriteriaUtils.java:107) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.orm.hibernate.HibernateCriteriaUtils.buildCountCriteria(HibernateCriteriaUtils.java:97) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hcentive.utils.search.service.CriteriaBasedSearchService.search(CriteriaBasedSearchService.java:38) ~[utils-1.5.jar:na]
    ... 104 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It'd better to post the complete stack trace. Otherwise, not sure that the exception is raised from date conversion or from hibernate.

Comment: Problem is clear from the log. Isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: unparseable date exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception)

Comment: This is a different issue as its not just formatting. Filtering the records from db is needed.

Comment: Add more code and complete stacktrace to understand the issue better. The stacktrace says issue started at`DateFormat.parse()` which is called by `HibernateCriteriaUtils.getSubCriterion`. Looking at code in your post is not giving any idea on what you are trying to do and whether the issue started before hitting the DB or after hitting the DB.

Comment: @Neha what is the value of the date from the DB? Check again if the date is `"25-Aug-14 00:00:00.000000000 AM"` (like in the log) or `25-AUG-14 11.26.16.369000000 AM`. I think the problem lies somewhere here.

Comment: @Sufian value in db is "25-AUG-14 11.26.16.369000000 AM"

Comment: Have you run code line-by-line (debugging)? It's still no known which line it causing the crash.

Comment: @Chaitanya OP has posted the complete stacktrace. Please check

Comment: @Sufian, the issue started at `com.hcentive.utils.orm.hibernate.HibernateCriteriaUtils.getSubCriterion` which is a custom code used by the OP, so it is difficult to analyze without knowing what they are doing in their custom code.

Comment: @Neha please respond to what Chaitanya says. You need to check `HibernateCriteriaUtils.java` of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is on the following line:

```
Date filterDate = ConversionUtils.convertFromString(value);
```

The reason is that the `SimpleDateFormat` used in the [ConversionUtils.convertFromString()](https://github.com/vaibhavguptaIITD/BlogWebApp/blob/master/site-utils/src/main/java/com/vaibhav/utils/ConversionUtils.java) is `MMMM d, yyyy`, while you're passing it `25-AUG-14 11.26.16.369000000 AM`.

Comment: The value passed in convertFromString() is "08/25/2014". which is the value given by user from UI. This needs to be parsed and converted to format in DB which is Timestamp so that the result can be filtered based on the date.

Comment: Post your complete stacktrace in your question.