# ParseException when parse date via SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse date from string to `Date`
My string date is: `Fri Apr 30 01:20:29 +0700 2010`

My code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");            
Date date = format.parse(input);
```

But i'm getting an Unparsable date exception.
What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `EEE` instead of `E` ?

Comment: Have a look at the examples @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: unparseable date exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception)

Comment: Yes, i tried to use EEE instread of E. Unfortunately, catch exception too.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed the docs say "For parsing, both forms [long/short names] are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters."

Comment: See my answer below about lang

Comment: Yeah, just added Locale.US and this work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your format, you only have one `E` instead of three :

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy
```

---

**EDIT** : also check your JVM's language locale or specify one for your call.

As writen in comments, following code works :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: WTF is an "application lang"?!

Comment: I still wouldn't agree that there's something like an "application locale".

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);` works fine

Comment: @Hanno : Do you mean it's not defined for the application itself but more for the JVM ?

Comment: I mean there's a system's default locale, which is what the application uses whenever it needs a locale and you don't provide one explicitly. But I may be nitpicking. Oracle says "The default locale is a systemwide resource, available throughout your application to any locale-sensitive object".

Comment: @HannoBinder To clarify, "system" means JVM, not computer.

Comment: "the JVM determines the default locale from the host environment. The host environment's locale is determined by the host operating system and the user preferences established on that system."

Comment: Yes but when calling `Locale.setDefault()`, it will obviously not change your host preference.

Comment: Calling `Locale.setDefault()` does not affect the host OS, but it *does* changes the current default for **all code in all threads in all apps running in that same JVM**. Changes on-the-fly at runtime, affecting all apps immediately. So you should almost **never call this**; do so only as a last resort. Ditto for [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). Instead, specify the desired/expected Locale or time zone as parameters passed to the methods. P.S. Use java.time instead of these tired old outmoded classes.