# Simpledateformat Error - unparseable date Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing, parseexception, unparseable

I am receiving this standard date time from server:

> Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015

I use this code to covert it into date:

```
DateFormat formatter;
//"Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

But it's giving me error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015" (at offset 20)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception

Comment: Please can u test ... i have gone through lots of post... but still its getting error... @IntelliJAmiya It will be really helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The input has weekday and month name in English, so it's **probably** a locale issue. `SimpleDateFormat` uses the system's default locale if you don't specify one  - check the value of `java.util.Locale.getDefault()` in your system, probably it won't be `en` (English).

If you set the locale, things should work:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.parse("Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015"));
```

---

## New Java Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

One big difference is that the new API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CET` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. In your case, `CET` is a shortcut for "Central European Time", but there are more than 30 different regions (or timezones) that uses `CET` abbreviation:

> Europe/Ljubljana, Europe/Rome, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Europe/Berlin, Africa/Ceuta, Africa/Algiers, Europe/Zurich, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Amsterdam, Poland, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Gibraltar, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Malta, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Vienna, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Vaduz, Europe/Warsaw, Europe/Prague,  Europe/Skopje, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Paris, Africa/Tunis, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Tirane, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Belgrade, Arctic/Longyearbyen, Europe/Monaco

I've chosen one for this test, but fell free to choose the one that suits best for your system.

```
// create formatter (this is thread-safe, while SimpleDateFormat isn't)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // pattern for date/time
    .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
    // timezone (use Europe/Berlin as prefered value for CET)
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Collections.singleton(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")))
    // year
    .appendPattern(" yyyy")
    // use English locale to parse weekday and month name
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

// ZonedDateTime is a date and time with a timezone
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015", fmt);
System.out.println(z); // 2015-12-14T13:25+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

The output will be:

> 2015-12-14T13:25+01:00[Europe/Berlin]

If you want a custom format, you can use the formatter as well:

```
System.out.println(z.format(fmt)); // Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015
```

The output will be:

> Mon Dec 14 13:25:00 CET 2015