# My app crashes as soon as I click on OK after selecting the date

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the code that I used in kotlin and it is running fine but the app crashes as soon as I click ok after selecting the Date of Birth. The app worked fine till displaying just the date but it is crashing as soon as I used the minutes

```
fun Calendara(){

    val Mycalendar= Calendar.getInstance()
    val Year=Mycalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month=Mycalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val DayOfMonth=Mycalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    var dpd=DatePickerDialog(this,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, Month, dayOfMonth ->
           Toast.makeText(this,"$DayOfMonth-$month-$Year",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val selectedDate="$DayOfMonth/${month+1}/$Year"
            datet?.text=selectedDate

            val sdf=SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
             val thedate=sdf.parse(selectedDate?.toString())

             val thedateinMinutes = thedate.time / 60000

            val currentdate = System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000

            val difference = currentdate - thedateinMinutes


            minutes?.text = difference.toString()

                                           },
        Year,
        month,
        DayOfMonth
    )
    dpd.datePicker.maxDate=System.currentTimeMillis()-8640000
     dpd.show()

   }

}
```

Above is the code and below is the errow which is displayed when I run through the debugger

Error:
[image]

The output should display the date we selected and your age in minutes

Comment: You're trying to parse a date formatted as `dd/MM/yyyy` with a `dd.MM.yyyy` format pattern. probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009207/java-unparseable-date-exception).

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Your error was [image]

You notice the line: `Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 8/12/2022`.

The date value of **8/12/2022** is clearly incompatible with the specified format of **dd.MM.yyyy**. In order to fix the problem, either change your value to the format or the format to the value.

Comment: please do not post images of text. if you must (because of decoration/etc) also add plain text form of the text for better indexing and searching

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Please tell the OP that. The image comes from the question (originally a link from the question, which of course only makes it worse).

Comment: fair enough. I somehow managed to overlook that :/